# Correct usage of AtomicCmpExchange?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, locking

After struggling to avoid deadlocks using `Synchronize()` with *DirectShow* I decided to switch to an optimistic lock pattern. This is my first time using `AtomicCmpExchange()` and I found very few Delphi examples online. I don't see any downside and don't know why more thread locking isn't done this way.

What are the pitfalls of the following code? The lack of examples make me concerned that there is a fundamental flaw with this approach.

```
procedure TCueRunner.Lock(Desc: String);
begin
  //  cs.Enter;
  var StopWatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  while (AtomicCmpExchange(LockAtomic, 1, 0) = 1) do
  begin
    Sleep(1);
    if StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > MUTEX_TIMEOUT then
    begin
      LockAtomic := 0;
      LogMsg('CRITICAL! TCueRunner lock timed out in function '+Desc);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TCueRunner.Unlock;
begin
  LockAtomic := 0; // This should be an atomic operation
  //  cs.Leave;
end;
```

Comment: The flaw is lava. :)

Comment: You probably don't want to reset the LockAtomic in case of timeout. But it is impossible to answer your question because it misses the context. It all depends on what kind of code (functionality) you are protecting with that. Also, if you have problem with deadlocks then this code will not prevent issues - just because you have timeout that will prevent deadlock does not mean that your code will behave correctly. Also such spin locking does not provide equivalent functionality as critical sections or Synchronize. Those are all different mechanisms that have particular use cases.

Comment: The deadlock I am try to get around is a documented issue with accessing COM objects (in my case DS). I cant change Syncronize to Queue because I need the media to play at the correct point in the code. https://marc.durdin.net/2012/08/waitforsingleobject-why-you-should-never-use-it/

Comment: Fair point about not resetting LockAtomic. Its a bit redundant the way the code currently is anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First, your lock cannot be recursively used. It's not always an issue, but it's usually worth it to make it work recursively as it's pain to always make sure it's not used in this fashion.

Second, as commented by Dalija, it's not really an expected behavior that a lock attempt that timeout would cause the lock to be automatically unlocked.

Third, if locking fails, your method should raise an exception, otherwise, the calling code will proceed as if the lock had succeeded. Alternately, you could change your method to a function returning a boolean indicating if the lock succeeded or not.

If I adapt your code, that would give something like this (Untested) :

```
procedure TCueRunner.Lock(Desc: String);
begin
  var StopWatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  repeat
    var PrevLockValue := AtomicCmpExchange(LockAtomic, TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID, 0);
    if PrevLockValue = 0 then //wasn't locked
      FLockCount := 1
    else if PrevLockValue = TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID then //Was locked previously, but by the current thread.
      Inc(FLockCount)
    else 
    begin //Is locked by another thread
      Sleep(1);
      if StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > MUTEX_TIMEOUT then
        raise Exception.Create('CRITICAL! TCueRunner lock timed out in function '+Desc);
      CONTINUE;
    end;
    BREAK;
  until False;
end;

procedure TCueRunner.Unlock;
begin
  if LockAtomic = TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID then
  begin
    Dec(FLockCount);
    if FLockCount = 0 then
      LockAtomic := 0;
  end else
    LogMsg('Unlocking from the wrong thread!!!!');//Or not locked...  
end;
```

Note : This should work properly on WIN32/64, I'm unsure about other platforms.

Comment: I did not consider recursive use as I guess I assumed (bad) that this should never happen unless I was calling application.processmessages. I like this change and will study it further before adjusting my implementing.

Comment: I doubt I would raise an exception in my implementation as if the lock fails its not necessarily catastrophic to the code its protecting ("optimistic"). I would rather the user report an oddity that can be investigated via a log file than stop their show dead.

Comment: @Martin You put in a lock to prevent the "corruption" of a resource, but then if the resource cannot be accessed quickly enough, you're going to let it be corrupted (or at least risk it)? I can't think of a single use case where that makes sense.  I wouldn't let it slide past me on a code review. I don't know what this lock is protecting, but I'm pretty sure at least 99.99% of cases, I'd rather skip the access than skip the lock.

Comment: @Martin As for recursive call, it can happen if, within the lock, you call a function, that calls a function, that calls a function, that calls the lock.  For very simple process, it's not a problem, it's when a system grows that it can get messy.

Comment: I agree but I as the developer am the one that needs the information that the lock timed out. The end user just wants their show to keep going at all costs.
I use the MADexcept system in my software and I tell users that if the error dialog pops up then they can use the "Continue" button but the software will be in an unstable state. Most users press the "Continue" button because they would rather take the risk of the software being unstable than have to restart. I'm not trying to say that 99.99% is good enough just that I would rather this get captured by a log than interrupt a user.

Comment: @Martin If you can afford to not care about data integrity... Do as you wish. On the systems I work on, data integrity failure can lead to human life losses. I can't afford that level of neglect. Who knows, maybe you can. That's bad programming though. You should never, ever access the same resource from 2 threads at the same time without proper synchronization. Also, I'm not saying you should interrupt your user, I'm saying you should interrupt the access to the locked data. How it affects the user is entirely up to you. (Maybe show a Retry/Abort dialog for example)

Comment: So using this lock technique allowed me to locate the root cause of my issues (yes I left the RAISE in there). It turns out that it does not matter what type of lock is used, a call to TThread.Synchronize can deadlock your code. It effectively not much different to Application.ProcessMessages. I had assumed that Synchronize only ran the passed procedure but in fact it pumps the main message queue and if the main thread attempts to access the routine that called the Synchronize then you end up in a deadlock.

Comment: TThread.Queue was not an option because things can run out of order. Anything in the main thread will get run immediately and not actually be added to the queue. Mitov.Threading.MainThreadExecute was the solution as this has an option to queue the procedure correctly regardless of the calling thread.

Comment: @Martin A call to synchronize halt your thread while it waits for the main thread to execute your synchronized method. If you do the "synchronize" while you have locked your resources, and the main thread tries to wait on the lock, a deadlock will occur, indeed. Though, to be fair, holding a lock while you synchronize isn't really a good idea. But yeah, designing good and efficient multithreaded system is definitely not easy.